# How to save MediaElement content in an MP4 file?

Tags: c#, uwp, mp4, mediaelement

I have a UWP Desktop application for video editing in which I use a `MediaComposition` as a base, create a `MediaStreamSource` and then a `MediaSource`, in which I add some `TimedMetadataTracks`.

Finally, I created a `MediaPlaybackItem` from this `MediaSource` and used it as a MediaElement's PlaybackSource. Everything works fine, but now I need to save what's displayed on `MediaElement` to an MP4 file.

Any help is most welcome. Thanks.

Xaml

```
<MediaElement x:Name="mediaPlayerElement" 
                                AutoPlay="False" 
                                Margin="5"
                                Width="640" Height="480"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" />
```

Code Behind

```
MediaComposition Composition = new MediaComposition();
MediaSource mediaSource;
MediaStreamSource mediaStreamSource;

mediaStreamSource = Composition.GeneratePreviewMediaStreamSource((int) mediaPlayerElement.ActualWidth, (int) mediaPlayerElement.ActualHeight);

mediaSource = MediaSource.CreateFromMediaStreamSource(mediaStreamSource);

TimedMetadataTrack metadataTrack = new TimedMetadataTrack("ID_0", "Subtitle", TimedMetadataKind.Subtitle);

mediaSource.ExternalTimedMetadataTracks.Add(metadataTrack);

var playbackItem = new MediaPlaybackItem(mediaSource);

mediaPlayerElement.SetPlaybackSource(playbackItem);

playbackItem.TimedMetadataTracks.SetPresentationMode(0, TimedMetadataTrackPresentationMode.PlatformPresented);
```

Comment: AFAIK, it is not possible to change the video file like adding captions with UWP media API. Check WPF or WinForms API instead.

Answer (score 0):

The `MediaPlaybackItem.Source.ExternalTimedMetadataTracks.Add()` method that you are using in your scenario is designed to add external timed metadata tracks to the **MediaSource object** when the **MediaSource object** is playing.

It will not directly modify the media file. There is no UWP media API that could directly add caption data into the media file. You might need to find some Win32 API to complement your requirement.